# Twig: Key "0" does not exist as the array is empty but dump show array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I have a problem in Twig trying to show an array.

When I dump the variable `{{ dump(perfilServidor) }}`, I get:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => UypPerfilServidor {#6122 ▼
    -id: 1
    -idPerfil: 8
    -uypPerfil: UypPerfil {#363 ▶}
    -uypServidor: UypServidor {#6118 ▶}
  }
  1 => UypPerfilServidor {#6117 ▼
    -id: 2
    -idPerfil: 8
    -uypPerfil: UypPerfil {#363}
    -uypServidor: UypServidor {#6116 ▶}
  }
  2 => UypPerfilServidor {#6114 ▼
    -id: 3
    -idPerfil: 8
    -uypPerfil: UypPerfil {#363}
    -uypServidor: UypServidor {#6115 ▶}
  }
]
```

But when I try to dump one key of the array `{{ dump(perfilServidor[0]) }}`, it throws an Exception:

> Key "0" does not exist as the array is empty

And if I try to access another key, `{{ dump(perfilServidor[5]) }}`, it says that the array have the keys 0,1,2:

> Key "5" for array with keys "0, 1, 2" does not exist

I want to get one specific value of the array (without looping through the whole array) How do I get the values of the array without looping through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if i don't know anything about the application that you are building, i can tell you that it is a bad practice to use hard coded array keys, especially inside a template.

You should not give a whole array to a template if you only need one item. Remember that the template is only the view not your program-logic.

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I was expecting, but it helped me solve the problem in other way. Although I'm still curious, ¿why Twig is throwing that exception?

Comment: Not sure. Is the underlaying array an php array or an object like doctrines arrayCollection? Is it lazy loaded?

Comment: The array comes from converting a DoctrineCollection with _.getValues_ method

Comment: Sounds like a lazy load issue. Ask yourself if you need lazy loading. Often you might want to render something from all records a database table contains. In that case you ll be better query all the information in one query. Nice blogpost: http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/some-doctrine-2-best-practices/