# Access to object with twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a json structured in this way

```
{"elements": [
  {
   "number": 1,
   "details": {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test",
    "url": "https://img1.jpg",
   }
  },

 {
  "number": 2,
  "details": {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "test2",
    "url": "https://img2.jpg",
   }
  }]
}
```

I tried to access in this way

```
{% for article in elements %}
  <h1>{{article.number}}</h1>
  <p>{{article.details.text}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If I remove article.details.text it works, if I add it I have an error:

> "Key "text" does not exist as the array is empty."**

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203813/twig-key-0-does-not-exist-as-the-array-is-empty-but-dump-show-array) help?

Comment: tried your code, everything is working fine (twig v3). Although I had to remove the trailing `,` in each object definition (otherwise my php 7.3 issues a bad json syntax error). It's working either with decoding to objects or associative arrays.

Comment: What version of Twig do you have? Maybe you should consider upgrading your twig version.